# Why won't Visual Studio for Mac open a project created from SPA templates?

Tags: angular, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

**Full disclosure: This is the first time I have tried to do any .NET development on a Mac**

Visual Studio for Mac will not open an Angular project created at the CLI using dotnet new. Attempts to open the csproj file in Visual Studio for Mac result in an error message:

```
Could not save solution: /Users/aaron/Projects/ngApp/ngApp.sln" followed by "Load operation failed
```

Created a new .NET Core / Angular app using the "angular" SPA template from the command line by creating a new directory called "ngApp", changing in to that directory, and then typing "dotnet new angular". This generated a project with everything I would have expected inside (including a csproj file). The csproj file seems right based on my experience with the csproj files of projects created using "dotnet new" on Windows.

Attempts to open the csproj file in Visual Studio for Mac result in an error message: "Could not save solution: /Users/aaron/Projects/ngApp/ngApp.sln" followed by "Load operation failed".

- .NET Core SDK 2.2.101,
- Node 9.5.0
- NPM version 6.5.0
- Angular CLI 7.1.4

Am I missing something important here? Are there any logs that may help me figure this out?

Comment: There should be more information in the IDE log. The logs are available from the Help - Open Log Directory menu.

Comment: Just tried the same thing with VS Mac 7.7.2 but with the older .NET Core 2.1.302 sdk installed and that seemed to work.

Comment: @MattWard: Thanks! I was struggling to find those logs. Found an interesting error but don't know how to resolve it on a Mac:
`ERROR [2018-12-21 08:45:03Z]: Could not save solution: /Users/aaron/Projects/ngApp/ngApp.sln
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Users/aaron/Projects/ngApp/.#ngApp.csproj" is denied.`

Comment: @MattWard: Your suggestion to hit the logs was a good clue. I changed permissions for the entire directory and now it will load.. but won't build. 

`The specified task executable "dotnet" could not be run. ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/dotnet', CommandLine=' exec "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design/2.2.0/build/netstandard2.0/../../tools/rzc.dll" @"/var/folders/3h/jkccm8nd4rs76h06yh3h31mw0000gn/T/tmpcdd45a5e34114770a14829d3f6906666.rsp"', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file (MSB6003) (ngApp)`

Comment: Alright, I've looked at this situation with the help of some great folks, including folks on SO, and I think the issue is related to permissions and whatnot. I think the issue is related to having to sudo a bunch of stuff to get it to install / work which probably has environment variables all jacked up. I'm taking your log suggestion as the answer here. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the suggestion of @MattWard, I looked at the logs which showed me I had some permissions issues going on. Resolving that issue with chmod only uncovered more issues with permissions and environment variables. A complete reinstall of Node, .NET Core, and Visual Studio resolved the issue.

I am able to run `dotnet new angular` from the CLI, `npm install` to sort out Node packages, and then open the project in Visual Studio without issue.

** Be careful sudo-ing all the things. I will mess up your whole world. **